# Resizing rectangle transition on scroll gets cut off

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, rectangles

I'm trying to resize a rectangle on scroll, when the user scrolls down, the rectangle shrinks and when they scroll up the rectangle goes back to its original size. However, I've encountered a problem where if the user scrolls too fast, the rectangle doesn't have enough time to adjust its height before the user reaches the top/bottom of the page (thus not allowing the onScroll function to change the rectangle's height). No transition time is added for the resizing of the rectangle.

I'm assuming this is because the height of the rectangle is taken from the height of the div containing some text. The text also resizes on the scroll and there's a transition time of 0.4 seconds, which may be delaying the rectangle.

Is there a way to continue to allow the rectangle to resize itself, even after the user stops scrolling? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the skeleton of my code:

```js
    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
    var width = window.innerWidth;

    // shrink and grow are functions that change the font size of text

    function scrollFunction() {
      document.getElementById("rect").style.height = document.getElementById("menu").offsetHeight + (width / 100) + "px";
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
        document.getElementById("title").style.fontSize = shrink("title");
        document.getElementById("here").style.fontSize = shrink("here");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("title").style.fontSize = grow("title");
        document.getElementById("here").style.fontSize = grow("here");
      }
    }
```

```css
    #rect {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      height: clamp(40px, 10vw, 130px);
      background: white;
    }

    #background {
      height: 200vh;
    }

    #title {
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="background">
      <div id="rect" style="border: 2px solid green">
        <div id="menu">
         <div id="title">title</div>
         <div id="here">here</div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, the rectangle starts growing/shrinking but doesn't transform all the way if the user stops scrolling. The transition gets cut off. I want to know if there's a way for the transformation to continue when the scrolling stops.

Answer (score 0):

use `transform: scale(/* Your shrink size goes here, say 0.3 */)` for your rectangle.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? For the transition to be smooth, both the text div and rectangle should both adjust heights at the same time, which requires not setting a transformation scale before hand.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it